# how to put Images to a linkedlist?

Tags: java, android, linked-list

just want to ask how can you put Images to a linkedlist? because base for what I have seen so far is that string char are the most objects used in storing in a linkedlist. So I'm just curious if putting images to a linkedlist is possible or not, if it is can anyone pls give me a syntax on how to put a Image into a linkedlist. Because I am currently creating an app where you input a word using the keyboard like "A" after clicking the done button an Image of a letter A will appear on the next activity.

Comment: Although it is possible to place an Image in a LinkedList via the Bitmap object you wouldn't really want to do it. (it takes up a lot of memory) Instead you may want to have the linkedlist store references of where the image is stored so it can be loaded up later. Then send the path or resource id to your next activity and load the image from there.

Comment: I'll be honest Im a complete beginner in terms of using linkedlist so I would bluntly ask on how start the one you are suggesting me to do instead of using LinkedList via Bitmap object

Comment: Hi Allen, Need a little more information, Where are your pictures stored? For example in the res folders/asset folder/sdcard or online? How are you planning to use the linked list to find the correct image or image reference?

Comment: Hi Mr.Martin, sorry for not giving full information on my last reply I just recently joined stack overflow so Im new again sorry. Anyways going back to your question My pictures are stored in the res drawables.Regarding on your second question Im not quite sure how to call it but I'll try to explain on how my app flows so it here goes:

Comment: in the current activity i put edittext and a button, so that if the button click the value of typed in edittext will be passed in next activity, but the typed in edit text must be limited in 5 letters
in the next activity i setup a text view which get or display what i've type in the edittext in previous activity... i've already done this part...
then i also setup 5 image view in the next activity pertaining to my question...

Comment: *the linkedlist with image reference(image located in res/drawable folder) must be compared to each letter i've typed in the previous activity
so that image equivalent to the letter typed will be displayed...

i'm also wondering if displaying image in this method will be dynamically 
*for example, how about if i typed only 1 letter...(the image must be placed in center) or if i typed 2letters(the image equal to the letter displayed)
as if the image pushed whenever letter added

so in the end i think using linkedlist can avoid redundancy in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

In java it would look like this.

`List<Image> images = new LinkedList<Image>()`;

In android I would use Bitmap, like below,

```
List<Bitmap> images = new LinkedList<Bitmap>();
```

> I am currently creating an app where you input a word using the keyboard like "A" after clicking the done button an Image of a letter A will appear on the next activity.

I guess you are storing images somewhere. In that case you can just go with having image paths instead of Bitmap itself as storing bitmap can take a lot of memory. Using [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) will be a good option for you here.

```
 HashMap< String, String> s = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Hashmap will have key and value.

```
 s.put("A", "filepath to image which has a");
```

Now you can get the path to that file using key value like below.

```
 s.get("A");
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply gonna try this code later if I got home

Comment: again thanks for the reply hmmmm so I will use Hashmap Instead of Bitmap eh gonna research on what and how does a HashMap works again thank you.

Comment: Looks like JJPA answered your question better, he suggested HashMap instead of linkedlist as it holds 2 bits of information the key (your search term) and the data (your image reference), because you gave extra information "your image is held in resources folder" your image path would actually be an Integer "R.drawable. are stored as ints"

Comment: Looks like it, but thanks for helping me out too hope to see you on my future post questions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your extra information I suggest looking at Hashtables instead of LinkedList, that way you can store a searcheable search term as well as the image reference.

Because your images are stored in the resource drawable folder, your image path would actually be an "int" R.drawable... are int's, Hashtables requires the object version of this so "Integer".

```
    Hashtable<String, Integer> images = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    images.put("A",R.drawable.A);       
    String search = "A";
    if(images.containsKey(search)){
        ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
        img.setImageResource(images.get("A"));
    }
```

A quick and rough example above for a much more simpler search, try experimenting and looking up Hashtable for more information.

Comment: Thanks for giving a sample code gonna try this later and experiment and find more information about Hashtable just as you said

Comment: Hi mr.martin ita me again first thank you for helping me out last time I was able to display the Image but my problem now is displaying another image at the same I tried using nested if but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

you can use `LinkedList<Bitmap>`, keep in mind that this can waste alot of memory

Comment: thanks also for the fast reply, after hearing you say that it can waste alot of memory do have some suggestions on what should I use on the app I am currently developing?

Comment: use some sort of memory caching, such as http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html